# Linq query help

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 Lists, both are business objects.

First object is

```
public class Mail
{
   string id;
   string name;
   string address;
   ....
}
```

Second object is

```
public class DoNotMail
{
   string id;
   string otherinfo;
   ....
}
```

The lists are

```
List<Mail> _mailList
List<DoNotMail> _doNotMailList
```

I need to a linq query to get all the Mail items where the Mail.Id is not in DoNotMail.id

If this were normal sql, I think I'd do a left join where DoNotMail.id is null, but every attempt I tried to do it in linq isn't working right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest approach:

```
var doNotMailIds = new HashSet<string>(_doNotMailList.Select(x => x.id));
var mailItems = _mailList.Where(x => !doNotMailIds.Contains(x.id));
```

That's assuming you want want the full `Mail` items. If you only need their IDs, you can do it in one query:

```
var mailIds = _mailList.Select(x => x.id)
                       .Except(_doNotMailList.Select(x => x.id));
```

Comment: HashSet beats my answer out for speed.

Answer (score 1):

`var mailItem = _mailList.Where(x => !_doNotMailList.Contains(x.id));`

Answer (score 1):

If you override the Equals method in both classes you can use this:

```
_mailList.Except(_doNotMailList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var results = from m in _mailList
              where !(from nm in _doNotMailList select nm.Id)
              .Contains(m.Id)
              select m;
```

It is equal to not in un Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try

var query = from m in Mail
    where !(from d in DoNotMail
            select d.Id)
            .Contains(m.Id)
    select m;